# Keep the State of a Single Page from a BottomNavBar

Tags: flutter

I have two pages, one where you check out a stack of movies, where you can like the movie on the top of the stack and move to the next one, **PAGE A**, and a second one that presents the liked movies in a list **PAGE B**.

Every time that I like or dislike a movie, I can go to **PAGE B** and see the movies that I've liked, but when I return to **PAGE A**, the stack has been reset to wat it first was.

Is there a way to keep the state of **PAGE A**, and leave the **PAGE B** rebuilding every time I open it?

Here's what I have:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  static String id = 'home';
  //
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //
  List<Widget> _pages = [MovieStackPage(), LikedMoviesPage()];
  int pageIndex = 0;
  //
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
      child: _pages[pageIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
        icons: [...],
        iconSize: 25,
        elevation: 50,
        activeIndex: pageIndex,
        leftCornerRadius: 32,
        rightCornerRadius: 32,
        activeColor: User.color,
        inactiveColor: kAppIconGray,
        splashColor: User.color.withOpacity(.3),
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => pageIndex = index),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using a package for the BottomNavBar but that shouldn't be a problem.

> 

**Additional Info:**
Before, in the **body** I had an IndexedStack like this

```
child: IndexedStack(
  index: pageIndex,
  children: _pages,
),
```

But the problem was that the **PAGE B** didn't refresh the list, and I could never see the liked movies.

Comment: You could use `InheritedWidget` to store the state of your first page, there are a few ways to do it but just by using state `InheritedWidget` should do the trick.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html

Comment: @Neil should I use it for **PAGE A** or for **PAGE B**?

Comment: If you do it correctly it should be accessible from both pages but, you did mention that PAGE B will always reload so you should access it from PAGE A